# How to separate variables using awk and append it to Text file using ansible

Tags: shell, ansible, perl, ansible-playbook, awk

What I got as extra variable to ansible playbook is "CHOW_app/timmy_app1/johnn_app3/harper_app4/mona_app5". This is passed as single variable to the playbook. I have to separate it and save it in a text file in this format.

```
REVOKE CHOW app
REVOKE timmy app1
REVOKE johnn app3
REVOKE harper app4 
REVOKE mona app5
```

I think it can be achievable using awk command. But I dont know whether this can be done in Ansible playbook itself. Does anyone have any idea how we can separate it using awk and store it in a txt file in Ansible itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  - name: slash delimited template
    template:
      src: revoke.jinja
      # dest is the output file
      dest: /tmp/revoke
    vars:
      # "variable" is the input delimited var
      # Split it into a list of users
      revokes: "{{ variable.split('/') }}"
```

templates/revoke.jinja file contains

```
{% for user in revokes %}
REVOKE {{ user.split('_') | join(' ') }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is giving me result. But it is like this:
"REVOKE CHOW appREVOKE timmy app1REVOKE johnn app3REVOKE harper app4REVOKE mona app5" . Any idea how to get next REVOKE to new line. here it is appending to "app" word without going to new line instead.

I added "   newline_sequence: '\n'  " to the template module. But still it gave the same result

Comment: When testing on Linux, I got line feed endings (\n). Try adding whatever new line endings you need inside the for loop.

Comment: Yes. In Linux, I am getting the expected result. But I am creating this txt file in windows. There it is not appending to new line.